# Wrong screen size for ipad

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

My app traces Capabilities.screenResolutionX and Capabilities.screenResolutionY. This outputs 1024x768 for my ipad mini. Okay so i begin shaping my app with 1024 width and 768 height for landscape display.

The problem is that my 1024x768 content is put in the middle of the ipad screen with a white space on both the left and right side. So i test it even closer. I make a green square with these dimensions and place it at x:0 and y:0. It's still wrong. So is my ipad screen bigger than what  Capabilities.screenResolutionX outputs or is it just kinda bugged so you have to make everything some inches bigger?

In case it wasn't clear: It's only the width that doesn't match and have extra whitespace on both sides. The height is fine, an exact fit.

Comment: If the height is fine but the width is a problem then I assume the content is showing squashed?

Comment: Are you manually setting the resolution to 1024x768? Only the original iPad Mini still uses that resolution. Unless you are scaling the app up, it's going to use just 1/4 of the screen (all other iPads being sold are 2048x1536). When working with mobile apps, you need to make your layouts 100% flexible now. There are far too many displays, especially if you want to target Android and increasingly on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that requestedDisplayResolution is set to be high in the XML eg:-

```
  <iPhone> 
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
  </iPhone>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but i tried it and it didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

Use 'Full screen' in publish settings.